# The view created based on the dataset has data, but the result of the count is 0, which occasionally occurs

Tags: apache-spark

[image]
etl :  starrocks  ->  hive

Occasionally, there may be situations where the count is not 0 and the dataset has no data. Ultimately, it resulted in the inability to import data from starrocks to hive

[image]